сохранение данных в xml (android studio)
У меня есть xml файл в котором будут лежать переменные:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <text1>test</text1>
</resources>

эти переменные я ищу по id и вставляю в edittext:
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, null);
        final EditText editText1 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        String str1;

        File saveData = new File("saveData.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(saveData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        str1 = String.valueOf(doc.getElementById("test"));
        editText1.setText(str1);
        return v;
    }

при сборке проекта вылетает такая ошибка:
Can't determine type for tag '<text1>test</text1>'

Подскажите как можно исправить и так же хотелось бы узнать, как правильно записывать данные в xml;

А что вы вообще хотите и чем вас не устроило использовать SharedPreferences?

@woesss как я прочитал SharedPreferences используется в основном для настроек, а мне нужно просто сохранить данные от ввода пользователя

Он используется для хранения простейших данных в формате ключ-значение (и хранит их как раз в xml). Это самое простое и доступное "из коробки" что вы можете использовать для хранения данных в Андроид.

Этот вопрос похож на: сохранение информации в xml (android studio). Если вы уверены что это не так, нажмите [edit], дайте ясно понять, чем ваш вопрос отличается от дубликата и/или почему ответы на него не помогают решить вашу проблему.
